# Spotlight direction issue in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, lighting

My quat works perfectly for moving about the worldspace with my camera.

now I took from https://learnopengl.com/#!Lighting/Light-casters a shader program for lighting in which it uses Eucl geo for it's camera and refers to direction a camera.front. I can't figure out how to calculate the same thing with the quat model.

```
vec3 CalcSpotLight(SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    // diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 32);
    // attenuation
    float distance = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + 
    light.quadratic * (distance * distance));    
    // spotlight intensity
    float theta = dot(lightDir, normalize(-light.direction)); 
    float epsilon = light.cutOff - light.outerCutOff;
    float intensity = clamp((theta - light.outerCutOff) / epsilon, 0.0, 1.0);
    // combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(diffusefinal);
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(diffusefinal);
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(specfinal);
    ambient *= attenuation * intensity;
    diffuse *= attenuation * intensity;
    specular *= attenuation * intensity;
    return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
}
```

now it works perfectly when I use it's camera model that uses Eular Angles for moving about, so it comes with an easy conversion for a front facind direction.

However, After much research, i've found what kinda works.

`glm::vec3 front = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) * camera[currentCam].orientation();` -- this is what's suppose to represent a forward direction.

and `camera[currentCam].position()` is the vec3 location in worldspace of the camera.

```
lightMgr.SetProperty(Spotlight, spolight, position, -camera[currentCam].position());
lightMgr.SetProperty(Spotlight, spolight, direction, -front);
```

Why does it require inverting the camera position and direction? It technically works, but I can't move on because I can't wrap my head around why it works when you take negative location and direction, but not positive direction and direction, or any other combination of the two.

Comment: Your multiplication order looks wrong (unless you've stored all matrices in transposed form). Usually glm uses M * v for a matrix times vector multiplication (instead of v * M).

Comment: Please fix all the wrong words in your question. What is a quat (do you mean quad)? Eular -> Euler. Please also use proper capitalization and do not use strange abbreviation (like Eucl geo)